# Understanding the "is" keyword in typecript

Tags: typescript

I would like to understand a particular pattern I see in Typescript/Angular, which is the following:

```js
this.subscription = this.router.events
    .pipe(
        filter((routingEvent: any): routingEvent is NavigationEnd => routingEvent instanceof NavigationEnd),
```

From what I understood, the "is" keyword narrows down a **type**. That means that [Angular's RouterEvent](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent#description) class turned into its subclass `NavigationEnd`. We then check that `routingEvent` is of instance `NavigationEnd`. I have 2 questions:

- Wouldn't it be more efficient if we used 'map()' and say `routingEvent is NavigationEnd`?
- In `filter()`, we said that `routingEvent is NavigationEnd`. Does that change the output when we subscribe? If so, why  can't we just `return true` because we literally just declared that `routingEvent is NavigationEnd`?

Forgive me if these questions have flaws in them, as I am new to Typescript, but if anyone can help me, that would be very great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understood, the "is" keyword narrows down a type. That means that Angular's RouterEvent class turned into its subclass NavigationEnd.

Yes, but only if the function returns true. `routingEvent is NavigationEnd` means "i will return a boolean, and if i return true, typescript should assume the event is a `NavigationEnd`".

> Wouldn't it be more efficient if we used 'map()' and say routingEvent is NavigationEnd

That would do something entirely different. The purpose of the filter method is to *remove* events from the event stream. Mapping would keep everything, including things which are not NavigationEnd events.

> In filter(), we said that routingEvent is NavigationEnd. Does that change the output when we subscribe?

Yes. The fact that we're identifying the NavigationEnd events and then returning true or false will change what gets output at runtime. And the fact that we used the type `routingEvent is NavigationEnd` instead of `boolean` will allow typescript to reflect this type narrowing at compile time.

> If so, why can't we just return true because we literally just declared that routingEvent is NavigationEnd?

That's legal code, but it defeats the purpose and will cause bugs. The filter function has the goal of only allowing NavigationEnd events through. If you just return true, you allow *everything* to slip past the filter. And then the return type is a lie. You're telling typescript "i checked this, and it's a NavigationEnd.", but you didn't. Typescript will trust you at compile time, but then you'll get errors at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The `is` keyword in typescript is used to describe a [predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates).

Predicate are used in user defined type guards.

When you have

```
(routingEvent: any): routingEvent is NavigationEnd => routingEvent instanceof NavigationEnd),
```

You function introduces type safty by asserting the `routingEvent` is of type `NavigationEnd`

Comment: To summarize the use of a predicate in this use case - it tells Typescript `routingEvent` is of type `NavigationEnd` only if the return value of the function is true. Since `filter` also only emits values when that function returns true, the linter can infer all subsequent calls in the pipe will get a parameter of type `NavigationEnd`.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is meant for `static type checking` in your question it means we do not manipulate values, we just use typescript to define types to capture maximum type errors that we get due to incorrect types being assigned.

Now lets get into your questions.

> Wouldn't it be more efficient if we used 'map()' and say routingEvent is NavigationEnd?

Ans: No, because `map` will return all the values, the purpose of `filter` here is to use the javascript `instanceof` operator to filter out all the `NavigationEnd` events alone, so all other events (E.g. `NavigationStart`, etc do not get subscribed) that is why we use filter! Secondly, the `router.events` has a type of `Event_2` Below is the type definition of it

```
declare type Event_2 = NavigationStart | NavigationEnd | 
NavigationCancel | NavigationError | RoutesRecognized | 
GuardsCheckStart | GuardsCheckEnd | RouteConfigLoadStart | 
RouteConfigLoadEnd | ChildActivationStart | ChildActivationEnd | 
ActivationStart | ActivationEnd | Scroll | ResolveStart | 
ResolveEnd | NavigationSkipped;
```

As you can see its a union of all the router events, so its going to confuse typescript obviously when we subscribe to it!

So we use the `is` keyword to narrow the type and asset to typescript that the return type will be `NavigationEnd`

> In filter(), we said that routingEvent is NavigationEnd. Does that change the output when we subscribe? If so, why can't we just return true because we literally just declared that routingEvent is NavigationEnd?

Ans: No, typescript is just a dev layer entity, meaning it assists with development and does not interfere with the return values, its purpose is to help the developer catch errors and write clean code, note typescript does transform code to javascript, we got some operators that do transform to different structures when we convert them to javascript

[Typescript playgroud example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCm0BcMCGYCeMC8MYG8AoPARwHd4AnFIvPVCAEwDMbi68AvAD2ADcUARnZ4Avu3HjCoSLHJUccRFAD8AOgYt1PfgG4gA)

So to answer your question, typescript does not transform anything, the reason we use filter is to filter out events also we are returning boolean condition only when we do `routingEvent instanceof NavigationEnd`